# Count posts with iterator

Tags: php, post, count

can i count how many POST's are submitted as Field_Amount_1, Field_Amount_2, Field_Amount_3, etc... like this ?

```
$Counting = count($_POST['Field_Amount_']);
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: You can just do count($_POST).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the easiest way would be to correct your form like:

```
<input name="Field_Amount[]" type="text" />
<input name="Field_Amount[]" type="text" />
<input name="Field_Amount[]" type="text" />
```

This makes it post an array so `$_POST` would contain:

```
Array (
   'Field_Amount' => Array (
      0 => 'amount'
      1 => 'amount'
      2 => 'amount'
    )
)
```

Then you can just do `count($_POST['Field_Amount'])`

The other way would be to manually count all the all the elements:

```
$keys = array_keys($_POST);
$counted = count(preg_grep('/^Field_Amount_\d+$/', $keys));
```

If you also need to make sure you only track fields that are not empty then you could do supply an empty string as the second param to `array_keys`:

```
$keys = array_keys($_POST, '');
$counted = count(preg_grep('/^Field_Amount_\d+$/', $keys));
```

If you need to do more validation than that then you will need to manually loop.

Comment: That was the key! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST['Submit']) {

    $count=0;

    foreach( $_POST as $post ) {
        if( strstr($post, "field_amount_")) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    echo $count;
}
```